# Change ggplot legend title

Tags: r, ggplot2, title, legend

So this is my code for my ggplot. How do I easiest change the title of the legend? I know that I can just change my `gg_group` variable to `my_title <- c(rep("train",10), rep("validation", 10))`. But i want to just change the title to "`whatever I want`" without change any variables.

```
library(ggplot2)
y <- c(rnorm(10,1), rnorm(10,3))
x <- rep(seq(1,10,1),2)
gg_group <- c(rep("train",10), rep("validation", 10))

gg_data <- data.frame(y=y, x=x, gg_group=gg_group)

p <- ggplot(gg_data, aes(x=x, y=y, group=gg_group))
p + geom_line(aes(colour=gg_group))
```

I have also tried this code:

`p + geom_line(aes(colour=gg_group)) +
 scale_shape_discrete(name="Dataset",labels=c("Train", "Validation"))`

But this does not work. *Edit, check great snwer from Jaap and JasonAizkalns.

Comment: You might want to use `scale_color_discrete`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because you did not use a `shape` in your `ggplot` code. Instead you should use `scale_color_discrete` as follows:

```
scale_color_discrete("Dataset")
```

Answer (score 11):

@Jaap is correct. If you use `scale_color_discrete` you can change the name of the legend with name and you do not have to pass any arguments to `labels` as they will assume the names defined in your `colour` aesthetic. That is consider the differences between:

```
p + geom_line(aes(colour = gg_group)) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Dataset")
```

and

```
p + geom_line(aes(colour = gg_group)) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Dataset", 
                       labels = c("New Label 01", "New Label 02"))
```